# Add Artifactory repository via CLI or Rest

Tags: rest, authentication, repository, command-line-interface, artifactory

Is it somehow possible to configure Artifactory via a CLI or a Rest API?

For example I'd like to add users or repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like its possible to configure it via https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateRepository. But Artifactory Pro is necessary to use this features.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning the jfrog cli, which have some useful commands. No repo / user creation yet, but maybe soon. :-) .  https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory